# Redirect to Another Symfony Route from FilterControllerEvent Listener

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, listener

I am trying to set up a kernal.controller listener to redirect to another route when a function returns true. I have the route available to me but no way to set the controller from this route using `$event->setController()`.

*I'm getting the following error:*

> FatalThrowableError in FilterControllerEvent.php line 59: 
>   Type error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent::setController() must be callable, string given

Does anyone have suggestions on how I can complete this?

```
class BlockListener
{
    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $block = $this->blockService->checkForBlock($user->getId());

        if ($block instanceof Block) {
            // $block-getRoute() is a standard Symfony route string. It doesn't work!
            $event->setController($block->getRoute());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The answers are very puzzling.  Are you trying to do an actual redirect as the question implies?  Or just trying to set a different controller?  If you want to do an actual redirect then you need to listen to the kernel request event which allows returning a redirect response.  The docs have plenty of examples.

Answer (score 6):

We were able to get it working by using a Lambda function. Thanks for the help!

```
    if ($block instanceof Block) {
        $redirectUrl = $this->router->generate($block->getRoute());
        $event->setController(function() use ($redirectUrl) {
            return new RedirectResponse($redirectUrl);
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

You can modify options below as you wish.

**OPTION 1**

[Full details](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/xtjc/triggering-redirect-in-event-listener-with-on-kernel-exception-when-404-not-found-http-exception-occurs)

LISTENER

```
namespace Application\BackendBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
class KernelExceptionListener
{
    private $router;
    private $redirectRouter = 'application_frontend_default_index';

    public function __construct(Router $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $exception = $event->getException();

        if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
            if ($event->getRequest()->get('_route') == $this->redirectRouter) {
                return;
            }

            $url = $this->router->generate($this->redirectRouter);
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
            $event->setResponse($response);
        }
    }
}
```

SERVICE DEFINITION

```
services:
    application_backend.event_listener.kernel_exception:
        class: Application\BackendBundle\EventListener\KernelExceptionListener
        arguments: [@router]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException }
```

**OPTION 2**

[Full details](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/ju0q/overriding-controller-response-message-with-an-even-listener-in-symfony)

LISTENER

```
namespace Application\FrontendBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;

class PlayerListener
{
    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $message = 'Bye inanzzz';

        $event->setController(
            function() use ($message) {
                return new Response($message, 400);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

SERVICE DEFINITION

```
services:
    application_frontend.listener.player:
        class: Application\FrontendBundle\Listener\PlayerListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead:

```
$event->setController( $event->getController() );
```

I think it should work, but no guarantees.
This passes in the controller instead of a string, which is what your error indicates.

Comment: Why would this do anything at all?  Replacing the controller with the original controller?

Comment: @Cerad, it's based on what I [read here in Symfony's documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-controller) about it. The OP is doing pretty well the same thing, except there's an if statement. The setController function requires passing in a `controller` reference instead of a string, which I think should resolve the issue, unless the OP has some other needed functionality.

Comment: The controller event gives you the chance to change the already chosen controller.  Setting the controller to whatever is is already set to effectively does nothing.  The question itself is poorly worded.  Trying to "set the controller from this route" makes little sense.