# Symfony 3.4: Access doctrine within an EventListener

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-3.4

I am trying to access to doctrine within an EventListener which tests a database table, if it is invalid then the user will be redirected to a config page where he will fix the issues!

The test will be executed before every call to a controller, so I will use the Event kernel.controller:

[EDITED: SOLVED, TESTING AND REDIRECTING VERY FINE]

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class BuildReferencesEventListener
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    protected $em;
    /**
     * @var Router
     */
    protected $router;
    protected $references = [
        1 => 'oxygen',
        2 => 'pH',
        3 => 'pCO2'
    ];
    protected $redirect_route = 'references';
    protected $requestStack;
    protected $session;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager, Router $router, RequestStack $requestStack, Session $session)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function onKernelController()
    {
        $em = $this->em;
        $savedReferences = $em->getRepository('AdminBundle:ParamReference')->findAll();
        $references = $this->references;

        if (count($savedReferences) <= 0){
            $this->redirect();
        }

        for ($i =0; $i<count($savedReferences); $i++){
            if ($savedReferences[$i] !== $references[$i]) {
                $this->redirect();
            }
        }
    }

    public function redirect()
    {
        $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
        $route = $request->get('_route');
        $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('warning', 'You need to setup the references for the parameters before starting the work');
        if ($route != 'references'){
            $url = $this->router->generate('references');
            $redirect = new RedirectResponse($url);
            $redirect->send();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is services.yml

```
build.references:
    class: AdminBundle\EventListener\BuildReferencesEventListener
    arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', '@router', '@request_stack', '@session']
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add argument inside your service.yml event listner service section

```
Your.service:
    Class: AdminBundle\EventListener\BuildReferencesEventListener
    arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller }
```

And add this __cunstruct code inside your listner:

```
namespace AdminBundle\EventListener;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class BuildReferencesEventListener
{

    protected $em;

    function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        //TO DO call doctrine
        // $em = Enity Manager...
        // $em->getRepository...
        // I hope its clear enough what im trying to do
    }
```

Comment: Before i try this, can you give me an example of how to name the service? because you say Your.service, but i dont anderstand much this form.

Comment: your event could have a name like `build.reference.event` it could be whatever you like and easily you could call in your application like a service `$this->get('build.reference.event')`. $this is for object container, if some where you are not getting directly a container then use call like this `$this->container->get('build.reference.event')`. For more better understanding read the documents here: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-simpler-service-configuration

Comment: if you got a working answer then mark as correct, tha's way other developers will focus on other issues to help more.

Comment: I am trying to get an Http response like rendering a view or redirecting to route! is that possible? check the code above i made an Edit.

Comment: Yes you could redirect to a route

Comment: To better understanding look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40433405/redirect-to-another-symfony-route-from-filtercontrollerevent-listener

Comment: I have to take a flight, so that giving you reference, else I was willing to help you better for symfony 3.4. if still facing any problem put here or add a new question, but first search because it might be possible you would get a better answer which has been given already.

Answer (score 2):

In Symfony 3.4 and above, autowiring is enabled by default, so you just have to add a type-hinted argument to your service's constructor method and a private property to assign the argument's value to.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;

class BuildReferencesEventListener
{
    private $em;

    public __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $em = this->em;
        // [...]
    }

}
```

---

If you need to
 declare arguments explicitly, you could do this in your service configuration:

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    # ... same code as before

    # explicitly configure the service
    AdminBundle\EventListener\BuildReferencesEventListener:
        arguments:
            $em: '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager_interface'
```

This could be useful to pass parameters that the service container doesn't know.

To learn more about the service container, https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container.html#injecting-services-config-into-a-service.

Comment: I am trying to get an Http response like rendering a view or redirecting to route! is that possible? check the code above i made an Edit.

Comment: Cannot autowire service "AdminBundle\EventListener\BuildReferencesEventListener": argument "$entityManager" of method "__construct()" references class "Doctrine\ORM\  
  EntityManager" but no such service exists. Try changing the type-hint to one of its parents: interface "Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface", or interface "Doctrine\  
  Common\Persistence\ObjectManager".

Comment: Have you tried doing that? Replacing the type-hint with one of the proposed interfaces?

Comment: The 1st anwser works fine, i just need to add the argument to the config